# phonegap build and contacts plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I developed a cordova app which uses the contacts plugin. I tested it on android with my linux machine and everything works fine. Now I am trying to use phonegap build to create an ios package. My problem is with the contacts plugin, the code for getting contacts doesn't work when I use it in IOS. I tried adding this line to my config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" version="0.2.11" />
```

But it didn't help.
The UI also looks different (everything is smaller). This is not an IOS compatibility issue -  I tried the apk created by phonegap build for android on the same android phone I used for development and the UI has the same problems it had on IOS. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to config.xml

```
<feature name="Contacts">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
</feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

For android you have to use this

```
<feature name="Contacts">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager" />
</feature>
```

Please refer this for more details
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html

Comment: Tried it, didn't help.